# Add border to left of numbered bullet AND indent text

Tags: html, css

This is a follow-up to a question that I just had answered. However, I realize that the solution caused another problem in my actual code.

I have an OL list of numbered LI items. I want to put a left border around each separate LI element OUTSIDE (left of) the number. I also want the lines to be properly indented, such that line 2+ appears directly below line 1 of a step.

Here's the latest fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/z7gkLnc7/5/

(I want to keep the div wrapper around the LI elements.)

```
<ol>
    <div class = "li_wrapper">
        <li>I am a line. A long line that keeps on going. It's what I do and who I am.</li>
    </div>
    <div class = "li_wrapper">
        <li>I am a line</li>
    </div> 
</ol>
```

Styles:

```
.li_wrapper{
    font-size:20px;
    margin-top:10px;
}

li{
    border-left:red 2px solid;
    list-style-position: inside; // Fixed border position, but how to fix indent?
}
```

Comment: This code is invalid. You can not have `<div>` in `ol`.

Comment: Why do you want to wrap the `li` with a div? Be sure that there are always valid alternatives...

Comment: The div isn't really the issue. It's not about the div.

Comment: Regardless of the invalid markup, you could reset the padding of the ordered list to 0 and give each list item a left padding. That's it!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z7gkLnc7/8/ use `pseudo` element for adding `|`

Comment: Vitorino, That still has the red line in the wrong location compared the the bullet number. Hashem, I don't see what you mean: I tried it http://jsfiddle.net/z7gkLnc7/10/

Comment: You just need this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/z7gkLnc7/16/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this ?

```css
.li_wrapper{
    font-size:20px;
    margin-top:10px;
    padding-left:30px;
    border-left:2px solid red;
}
li{list-style-position: outside;}
```

```html
<div><b>
   I'd like for the red lines to be to the left of the numbers AND for the text to be indented. 
    </b>
</div><br/><br/>


<div>
    Red line is, incorrectly, to the right of the number:
</div>
<ol id = "one">
    <div class = "li_wrapper">
        <li>I am a line. A long line that keeps on going. It's what I do and who I am.</li>
    </div>
    <div class = "li_wrapper">
        <li>I am a line</li>
    </div>
</ol>

<div>
    Text is not indented:
</div>
<ol id = "two">
    <div class = "li_wrapper">
        <li>I am a line. A long line that keeps on going. It's what I do and who I am.</li>
    </div>
    <div class = "li_wrapper">
        <li>I am a line</li>
    </div>
</ol>

<div>
   Cannot mix and match. Not right.:
</div>
<ol id = "three">
    <div class = "li_wrapper">
        <li>I am a line. A long line that keeps on going. It's what I do and who I am.</li>
    </div>
    <div class = "li_wrapper">
        <li>I am a line</li>
    </div>
</ol>
```

Comment: just as a side note, I meant to change the div class li wrapper to ul's with list style type none.

Comment: The steps are still not indented properly. The second line starts below the bullet number, not below the line 1 text.

Comment: Yes, now it's perfect. For me, this is the best answer because it's closer to the html/css that I've already got. (although, apparently I shoudl not have wrapped an LI with a DIV ) 
I made a simplified fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/z7gkLnc7/15/

Answer (score 1):

You can use display:table on the ol and then set your own counter:

http://jsfiddle.net/4rnNK/867/

```css
    ol,

    li {

      margin: 0;

      padding: 0;

    }

    ol {

      counter-reset: foo;

      display: table;

    }

    li {

      list-style: none;

      counter-increment: foo;

      display: table-row;

      padding-left: 1em;

    }

    li::before {

      content: counter(foo)".";

      display: table-cell;

      text-align: right;

      padding-right: .5em;

      padding-left: .3em;

      border-left: red 2px solid;

    }
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    omnis ab quasi voluptatem voluptatem consequuntur sed fugit beatae veritatis sed quae dolores iste quasi ipsam ipsam, perspiciatis sed inventore eaque totam inventore sed ut sit dolores perspiciatis inventore ipsa totam ipsam ipsam,
  </li>
  <li>
    et consequuntur error totam quia ipsa odit aspernatur accusantium vitae ipsam ipsam, enim voluptatem eaque ratione vitae ipsam qui odit ratione enim ipsa ipsa natus quae laudantium quae rem
  </li>
  <li>
    nemo ab ratione sunt sit rem magni sit fugit unde unde, inventore magni magni ab qui eos ab natus sunt nemo ab fugit
  </li>
  <li>
    omnis error rem enim ipsam ipsam, perspiciatis qui eos inventore laudantium vitae quasi voluptas eaque aut error vitae voluptatem consequuntur aspernatur consequuntur inventore fugit qui ipsa ipsa, quia
  </li>
  <li>
    ipsa ipsam ipsam illo explicabo sit vitae vitae, qui doloremque quae aspernatur aperiam beatae ratione ut aperiam sed dicta qui ipsam ipsa voluptatem voluptatem, error ratione aut rem ipsa
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: That works, thanks! I updated the fiddle so it's just one of the steps that has the border, which is what I'll eventually need: http://jsfiddle.net/4rnNK/868/